# printing to file the duration of chrono

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I'm trying to print to the file amount of microseconds:

```
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds> (t2-t1).count();

fprintf(file, "%lu, %lu\n", dutation1, duration1);
```

In the file I can see the first column having some values around 2000 but
I get second column values always equal to zero. I wonder if I'm doing correct `fprintf` (the `%lu` parameter) and why does it print the second variable as zero in the file?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your problem, but why are you using the old C `FILE*` output instead of C++ streams?

Comment: I had to change existing code, but yes now i'm thinking about rewriting it with c++ streams.

Comment: i wonder that your code compiles. the 3rd argument seems to be misspelled `du**t**ation`

Comment: @guenni_90 thats typo, i wasn't copy pasting the code. but typing here.

Comment: Additionally [this library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#duration_io) can be used to stream `durations` to C++ streams without using the `.count()` member.  This will automatically add the units for the `duration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) function returns a type called `rep`, which according to [this `std::duration` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) is

> an arithmetic type representing the number of ticks

Since you don't know the exact type, you can't really use any `printf` function to print the values, since if you use the wrong format you will have *undefined behavior* (which is very likely what you have here).

This will be easily solved if you use C++ streams instead, since the correct "output" operator `<<` will automatically be selected to handle the type.